# Airflow Passing DataFrames Between Python Operators

Tags: python, airflow

I tried looking for this answer but could not find anything that makes sense for what I am trying to do.

I am trying to create a DAG that will grab a file from a FTP and return a data frame, clean the data frame, and then import to SQL. So it will end up looking like:

`connect_to_ftp >> get_file >> clean_dataframe >> import_to_sql`

So if I wanted to get the dataframe in one operator, and the pass it into another, how would I do this? Do I use xcom variables, or should I just make global variables in my code?

Answer (score 1):

So I read in the docs:
https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#operators

Operators should be atomic and should rarely pass data to each other. So I guess im thinking about it wrong?

Comment: Consider downloading the file then passing the filename around instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. That said, I've seen implementations where the data is passed around instead. Tbh, I'm not sure which is better, or whether Airflow is a good tool for ETL at all.

Comment: @absolutelydevastated May I ask, which flows out there that you think is suitable for scheduling ETL and be able to give us good visibility compared to Airflow?

Comment: @ApichartThanomkiet Unfortunately I'm just getting started with ETL pipelines myself so I don't really know what are the alternatives.